# Connecting to containerised MongoDB replica set with Docker results in "Canonical address ... does not match server address."

Tags: java, mongodb, docker-compose, quarkus, mongodb-replica-set

I am trying to connect to my local MongoDB replica set (configured via Docker Compose) via an application running on Quarkus, however I am getting the following logs as soon as I try to access the database via the application:

```
2022-01-25 13:18:30,299 INFO  [org.mon.dri.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='61efea96e5029b1a675a4312', description='null'}-mongo3:27023) Canonical address mongo3:27017 does not match server address.  Removing mongo3:27023 from client view of cluster
2022-01-25 13:18:30,303 INFO  [org.mon.dri.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='61efea96e5029b1a675a4312', description='null'}-mongo2:27022) Canonical address mongo2:27017 does not match server address.  Removing mongo2:27022 from client view of cluster
2022-01-25 13:18:30,306 INFO  [org.mon.dri.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='61efea96e5029b1a675a4312', description='null'}-mongo1:27021) Server mongo1:27021 is no longer a member of the replica set.  Removing from client view of cluster.
```

Which eventually leads to a ConnectionException to be thrown and the following error log:

```
2022-01-25 13:18:35,304 ERROR [nl.rab.kno.int.LoggingInterceptor] (executor-thread-0) LoggingInterceptor.MethodCallEvent(className=nl.rabobank.knowledge.service.PreferencesService, methodName=getLanguagesForUser, result=EXCEPTION, exception=com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@4fe08d8a. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=mongo3:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}, {address=mongo2:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}, {address=mongo1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}])
```

For some reason it seems to automatically remove the node from the client view when the application tries to connect to the database for reading/retrieving data. I am wondering what goes wrong here?

I simply followed this guide for setting up a replica set in MongoDB with Docker Compose: https://blog.tericcabrel.com/mongodb-replica-set-docker-compose/. Note that the application is able to successfully connect to the database when I create a non-containerised replica set (as also explained in the same tutorial). I
therefore have the feeling that this issue is occurring due to something being misconfigured with my containerised setup.

This is the connection string that I am using in my Quarkus application:

```
quarkus:
    mongodb:
        connection-string: mongodb://mongo1:27021,mongo2:27022,mongo3:27023/database?replicaSet=dbrs
```

These are the dependencies used by my Quarkus application (version 2.6.2):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-panache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you modify your hosts file ?
Because the hostnames mongo1, mongo2, mongo3 are only resolvable from the Docker network so if you launch your apps out of the docker compose you should use localhost or modify your hosts file.

Comment: Yes, I did indeed updated my host file with an entry per hostname, like: mongo1          127.0.0.1. But I am not launching my app from the docker compose and that is actually complicating things and resulting in the above 'error' scenario.

Comment: Check your configurations port numbers!  mongo3:27023 vs. mongo3:27017  (and same with nodes 2 and 1).  mongod process must (of course) run on same port what you configure in connection string AND rs.conf()

Comment: I aligned them, but no luck unfortunately. Running into another exception thenL com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream. Note that I am running the Mongo replica set containerised locally (configured via Docker Compose), but not the application itself connecting to the replica set, which is just configured to run locally.